# Need help about decompiling contract code

Tags: solidity

When i tried to decompile smart contract in Polygon network, i got this result. But there is no functions and other stuff displayed, where is it located?

[Decompile result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cIBD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The decompiled output suggests that the contract is a diamond proxy ([EIP](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2535), and example [implementation](https://github.com/mudgen/diamond-3/blob/master/contracts/Diamond.sol)) which doesn't need any more functions apart from the `fallback()`, and any more properties except for the mapping.

Simply said, diamond is a proxy pattern that makes use of splitting large contracts into multiple implementation addresses to match the max contract size limit. The mapping stores a relation between each implementation function selector and the address where this function is present, and the fallback redirects the request to this implementation address (based on the function selector).

So the actual implementation is split between multiple addresses that are stored in the mapping. You should be able to reverse engineer the actual implementation addresses based on the previously recorded transactions to the proxy address.